# Как узнать является ли класс наследником от другого класса?

Tags: java

Как узнать является ли класс наследником от другого класса в рантайме?
instanceof этого не проверяет. Смотрел в сторону isAssignableFrom(), но что-то не выходит. Кто имел опыт?

Comment: Класс я беру через obl.getClass()

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Пример:

```
public class Test {

    public class A {}

    public class B extends A {}

    public class C {}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("B extends A : " + A.class.isAssignableFrom(B.class));
        System.out.println("C extends A : " + A.class.isAssignableFrom(C.class));
    }
}
```

Результат:

```
B extends A : true 
C extends A : false
```